# Shrinking an ArrayList to a new size

Tags: java, arraylist

Do I really need to implement it myself?

```
private void shrinkListTo(ArrayList<Result> list, int newSize) {
  for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= newSize; --i)
  list.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: FWIW the neater way to write that is "while length > limit, remove the last one" !

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Create a [sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) with the range of elements you wish to remove and then call [`clear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear--) on the returned list.

```
list.subList(23, 45).clear()
```

This approach is mentioned as an idiom in the documentation for both [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) and [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-).

---

Here's a fully unit tested code example!

```
// limit yourHappyList to ten items
int k = yourHappyList.size();
if ( k > 10 )
    yourHappyList.subList(10, k).clear();
    // sic k, not k-1
```

Comment: +1 probably the fastest implementation that retains the pointer to the original

Comment: Confirmed by official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int). "For example, the following idiom removes a range of elements from a list:      list.subList(from, to).clear(); "

Answer (score 8):

alternatively you can use [subList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList) method:

```
public static <T> List<T> shrinkTo(List<T> list, int newSize) {
    return list.subList(0, newSize - 1);
}
```

Comment: yea but this does not affect the original list. maybe the elements to be removed are no longer needed and he wants to free them; this method would not accomplish that.

Comment: @dfa No, the GC can't remove the original list, at least in the case of ArrayList (which is by far the most common case) if you have a look at the source code (for ArrayList) you'll see that `list.sublist()` returns a `SubList` object that happens to have a reference to the original list, hence the GC can't claim the original list. Maybe if you edit your answer to return `new ArrayList(list.subList(0, newSize - 1))` instead then we get rid of the reference to the original list

Answer (score 7):

use [ArrayList#removeRange()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange) method:

> protected void removeRange(int fromIndex,
>                              int toIndex)
>
> Removes from this list all of the elements whose index is between fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. Shifts any succeeding elements to the left (reduces their index). This call shortens the list by (toIndex - fromIndex) elements. (If toIndex==fromIndex, this operation has no effect.)

then use [ArrayList#trimToSize()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize()) method:

> Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance.

Comment: if you cannot subclass, try subList (check my second answer)

Answer (score 4):

My solution :

```
public static void shrinkTo(List list, int newSize) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (newSize >= size) return;
    for (int i = newSize; i < size; i++) {
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Just use :

```
shrinkTo(yourList, 6);
```

Comment: Complexity will be O(n*k); k = numbers need to be removed. In worst case it would go till O(nˆ2).

Comment: list.subList(newSize, size).clear(); instead of for loop will make your code time complexity to O(n)

Answer (score 1):

There is another consideration.  You might want to shy away from using an `ArrayList` in your method signature, and instead work to the `List` interface, as it ties you into the`ArrayList` implementation, making changes down the line difficult if you find that, for example, a `LinkedList` is more suitable to your needs.  Preventing this tight coupling does come at a cost.

An alternative approach could look like this:

```
private void shrinkListTo(List<Result> list, int newSize) {
  list.retainAll(list.subList(0, newSize);
}
```

Unfortunately, the `List.retainAll()` method is optional for subclasses to implement, so you would need to `catch` an `UnsupportedOperationException,` and then do something else.

```
private void shrinkListTo(List<Result> list, int newSize) {
  try {
    list.retainAll(list.subList(0, newSize);
  } catch (UnspportedOperationException e) {
     //perhaps log that your using your catch block's version.
     for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= newSize; --i)
        list.remove(i);
     }
  }
}
```

That is not as straight forward as your orginal.  If you are not tied to the instance of the List that you are passing in, you could just as easily return a new instance by calling `subList(int start, int end)`, and you wouldnt even need to make a method.  This would also be a faster implementation, as (in Java 6), you would be getting an instance of an `AbstractList.SubList` that contains your list, an offset into it and a size.  There would be no need for iterating.

If you are interested in the arguments for coding to Interfaces instead of classes, see [this favorite article by Allen Holub](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html)

Comment: using .retainAll() is going to be really inefficient. it will have to take O(n^2) because for each element of the list, it has to go through the sublist to check for it (it doesn't know that it's a sublist)

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
if (list.size() > newSize) {
    list = list.subList(0, newSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the util class I use.

```
public class ArrayUtil {
    public static <T>ArrayList<T> reduceSize(ArrayList<T> models, int size){
        int k = models.size();
        if ( k > size )
            models.subList(size, k).clear();
        return models;
    }
}
```

Call it in your main class

```
ArrayUtil.reduceSize(myArrayList, 10);
```