# Remove ith element from the ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I need to remove ith element from the list.

```
    List<MyElement> MyList = new ArrayList<MyElement>();
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
      MyElement em = new MyElement(i);
      MyList.add(em);
    }

    MyList.remove(3);
```

As a result MyList looks like this:

```
[0][1][2][4][null]
```

instead of this:

```
[0][1][2][4]
```

How to remove `null` element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shrinking an ArrayList to a new size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184636/shrinking-an-arraylist-to-a-new-size)

Comment: If you change the first `List` to `ArrayList`, does it work? I've always dealt with item removal using `ArrayList#remove(int)`

Comment: Is `MyList.size()` four or five after the call to remove?

Comment: I got ouput `[0][1][2][4]` :/ by running same code in online java compiler.

Comment: I was a bit surprised by your question because I never seen such a behavior before in Java. So I tried in eclipse and I can't reproduce it. Java collection manage automatically the size and content when removing and adding elements. By the way your sample code is wrong: you don't have any add part in it ! Maybe in your real code you have a last add statement that is using a null reference.

Comment: @Guillaume: well, ((ArrayList<MyElement>) MyList).trimToSize() helped solve this issue.

Comment: @Klausos: what is your compiler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `MyList.trimToSize()` after removing element.

Comment: Like this? ((ArrayList<MyElement>) MyList).trimToSize(); ?

Comment: or you can use ArrayList instead of List in this case.

Answer (score 2):

try this, it does not assume that the null is at the end.

```
Iterator<MyElement> ml = MyList.iterator();

while (ml.hasNext()) {
    MyElement em  = ml.next(); // must be called before you can call ml.remove()
   if (em == null) {
      ml.remove();
   }
}
```