# Find the largest value between two indexes in an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to find the highest value between two indexes in my ArrayList. I am very new to coding and am stuck. I have already written a method that finds the highest value of the entire ArrayList but when I try to write the method that looks between two indexes of my ArrayList and finds the highest value all I get is the highest value of the entire array list.

Here is the method that finds highest value for the whole ArrayList:

```
public int findMaxReadingIndex() {
        int maxValue = (int) sensorReadings.get(0).getValue();
        int maxIndex = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (SensorReading sensorReading : sensorReadings) {
            if (sensorReading.getValue() > maxValue) {
                maxValue = (int) sensorReading.getValue();
                maxIndex = i;
            }

            i++;
        }

        return maxIndex;
    }
```

and here is the method that is supposed to find the highest value between my startIndex and endIndex. In this case I want the startIndex to be 5 and the endIndex to be 13:

...

```
public int findMaxReadingIndex1(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
       startIndex = (int) sensorReadings.get(5).getValue();
       endIndex = (int) sensorReadings.get(13).getValue();
       int maxValIndex = 0;

       for (SensorReading sensorReading : sensorReadings) {
           if (startIndex < sensorReadings.size() && sensorReadings.size() < endIndex) {

               maxValIndex = findMaxReadingIndex();
           }
       }

            return maxValIndex;
    }
```

...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You kids and your newfangled iteration... back in my day, all we had was [for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Notice how you can set where they start (your start index) and where they end (your end index)? Pretty neat, huh?

Comment: Do you mean the largest difference between any two values in the list, or the largest difference between two consecutive values?  If it's the latter, do you care if it's ascending or descending?

Comment: You can create a new list from startIndex to endIndex. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1184665/2669814

Comment: size gives the size of the whole thing. You want an index into it. Do like in your first case where you set i, and then test if i is in your desired range of indices (so replace sensorReadings.size() with i). But really, I think a simple for loop would be easier, like @MarsAtomic said.

Comment: so you are trying to find out startIndex is larger or endIndex is large?

Comment: Also, no reason to change startIndex and endIndex.

Comment: have a look at the `sublist` function on `List`, to create a view on which you can then iterate

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses! ikdhruw & njzk2 I was thinking that I should make a sublist but I have never done that before so I will definitely try to learn about sublist use that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to think a regular for loop would be easier here, as in the other answers, but there is something to be said for following your approach since it was yours. It seems to me it is possible to tweak your original method ever so slightly.

```
public int findMaxReadingIndex1(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    int maxValue = (int) sensorReadings.get(startIndex).getValue();
    int maxIndex = startIndex;
    int i = 0;

    for (SensorReading sensorReading : sensorReadings) {
        if (i >= startIndex && i<= endIndex && sensorReading.getValue() > maxValue) {
            maxValue = (int) sensorReading.getValue();
            maxIndex = i;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return maxIndex;
}
```

and then if you don't want to repeat yourself, your findMaxReadingIndex() can call this method with parameters of 0 and sensorReadings.size()-1.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
IntStream                                               // Handy utility method for producing a stream of integers.
.range( 100 , 120 )                                     // Generate a stream from 100 to 119. Half-open approach means  we go up to, but do not include, the limit of 120.
.boxed()                                                // Convert an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`.
.collect( Collectors.toList() )                         // Collect the elements from this stream, feeding them into a newly instantiated `List`. 
.subList( 5 , 13 )                                      // Return a `List` of a subset of elements from the first list.
.stream()                                               // Produce a `Stream` of the elements in that `List`.
.max( Comparator.comparingInt( Integer :: intValue ) )  // Compare each element as an `int`. Perhaps there is a better way to do this comparison, to avoid auto-boxing from object to primitive.
.get()                                                  // Extract a value from an `Optional`.
```

> 112

## Streams

Let's get fancy by using streams.

First, we need a series of [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects for our demo.

We can loop to populate such a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

```
List < Integer > numbers = new ArrayList <>( 20 );
for ( int i = 100 ; i < 120 ; i++ )
{
    numbers.add( i );
}
```

Or use streams for this part too, as wall as for finding the maximum.

```
List < Integer > numbers = 
    IntStream
    .range( 100 , 120 )
    .boxed()
    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;
```

> numbers = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]

Find the maximum by using [`Stream::max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)).

Next we use [`List::subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) to get your desired subset of elements from the list. Then we make a stream of that sublist. Each element from the stream is fed through the [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) where the integer value is compared as a test. The maximum value found is returned with a call to [`Optional::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#get()).

```
Integer biggest = 
    numbers
    .subList( 5 , 13 )
    .stream()
    .max( Comparator.comparingInt( Integer :: intValue ) )
    .get()
;
```

> biggest = 112

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
public int findMaxReadingIndex1(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int maxVal = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;

    for(int x = startIndex; x <= endIndex; x++)
    {
        if(sensorReadings.get(x) >= maxVal)
        {
            maxVal = values[x];
            maxIndex = x;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("max value = " + maxVal);
    System.out.println("max index = " + maxIndex);

    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: sensorReadings is an array list, not an array, so wouldn't you need .get rather than []?

Comment: @JeremyKahan I can always count on you to catch my mistakes. :D My scratchpad version of this method used an array.

Answer (score 0):

Well either you're making this too complicated or I don't understand the requirement.

```
   public int findMaxReadingIndex1(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
      // set max to the first value
      int max = sensorReadings.get(startIndex).getValue();
      int maxIndex = startIndex;
      for (int i = startIndex+1; i <= endIndex; i++) {  
         int v = sensorReadings.get(i).getValue();
         if (v > max) {
            max = v; // save v
            maxIndex = i;
         }
      }
      return maxIndex;
   }
```